# How to get ID of element ViewChild angular2 and jquery?

Tags: jquery, angular

I need to have a relation between jquery and ViewChild of angular2

I tried this but I get undefined value

```
@ViewChild('item', {read: ViewContainerRef}) Item;

console.log( $(this.Item.nativeElement).attr('id')) );
```

update part

```
<div class="container col411 col-sm-4" id="div411Item" 
        style="border: 1px solid #9DA0A4;" (dblclick)="ActiveEditcol411()" #Item>
    new content
</div>

ActiveEditcol411(){
    $('#Item').prop('contenteditable','true');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You have an extra parenthesis in your code.

   > console.log( $(this.Item.nativeElement).attr('id')**)** );
2. Are you sure you have "id" attribute in your html tag? If you don't have one, add it and try the code below:
        console.log( $(this.Item.nativeElement).attr('id') );

Answer updated:

```
<div class="container col411 col-sm-4" id="div411Item"  style="border: 1px solid #9DA0A4;" (dblclick)="ActiveEditcol411()" #Item>
new content
</div>

@ViewChild('Item', {read: ViewContainerRef}) Item;

ActiveEditcol411(){
    $(this.Item.element.nativeElement).prop('contenteditable','true');

}
```

Comment: @khalil_diouri  Add more source code here or create a plunker. Where do you call console.log() ?

Comment: I add dynamically a Component in other Component when I add this component two times I have some elements in the main component with the some values of ID in view of is the same content some how to avoid this
(because I can get ID simply with jquery)
its because I tried to use ViewChild////////-------------------------------

I call console.log aftrer dbclick event !

Comment: when I show this (this.Item.nativeElement) in console.log I get unedfined
I dont understand why !

Comment: Mistake in  
@ViewChild('Item', {read: ViewContainerRef}) Item;   When you initialize ViewChild you should call it by it`s locale name: Item, not item.

Comment: I ran my code and it works fine for the code excerpt you`ve posted. I don`t know why it`s not working for you. Maybe you have additional code which has influence. You should better create a plunker to show people your problem in the context.

Comment: you see :D I missed **element** thank you very much for your time